# Swift - Implementing Equatable?

Tags: swift, operators

I have the following class that I want to have Equatable. Everything works fine excep it seems like the operator completely overrides the global == operator.

```
// User.swift
class User: Equatable {
    let id: Int

    init(_ id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.id == rhs.id)
}
```

It seems like in other places in the code when I try to use == it complains that "T is not convertible to User". But this is a completely different class and has nothing to do with user

```
// ArrayExtension.swift
extension Array {

    public func contains(object: T) -> Bool {
        for x in self {
            // Compile error here "T is not convertible to User"
            if (x == object) {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the T in the Array is not necessarily Equatable. You cannot use `==` in your extension because of that.

The reason you get that error is that the compiler is trying its best to find a function that can be used called `==`. It happens to be finding your `==` function but it gives an error because it doesn't actually match the types.

**Note:** The compiler could obviously use some usability work with its error messaging

Comment: Oooh I knew it had to be Equatable, but I was trying to solve the first issue before moving to the next. I think the error message is very confusing. Thanks for clarification